# Spring Boot method validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

## Problem

I have the following constraints on `userUuid` and `itemUuid`:

- Both strings must not be `null`.
- Both strings must be UUIDs (eg. `f1aecbba-d454-40fd-83d6-a547ff6ff09e`).
- The composition `(userUuid, itemUuid)` must be unique.

I tried to implement the validation in my controller like:

```
@RestController
@Validated // (1)
public class CartItemController {

    @PostMapping("/me/carts/{itemUuid}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable("itemUuid") String itemUuid,
                        Authentication auth) {
        CartItemId id = getCartItemId(getUserUuidFrom(auth), itemUuid);
        ...
    }

    @Unique // (4)
    public CartItemId getCartItemId(@NotNull @Uuid String userUuid, // (2)
                                    @NotNull @Uuid String itemUuid) { // (3)
        return new CartItemId(userUuid, itemUuid);
    }
    ...
}
```

`@Uuid` and `@Unique` are custom constraints. Method validation is enabled in `(1)`. `(2)` are the contraints for the user UUID. `(3)` are the constraints for the item UUID. The unique constraint is applied to the returned `CartItemId` in `(4)`. However, the parameters and the return value are never validated. Neither for the standard `@NotNull` constraint nor for my custom constraints. I receive HTTP status `201 Created` instead of `400 Bad Request`.

*What am I doing wrong?*

## Stuff that works

The following code works for the item UUID:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class CartItemController {

    @PostMapping("/me/{itemUuid}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable("itemUuid") @Uuid String itemUuid, // (1)
                        Authentication auth) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Adding the `@Uuid` to the path variable parameter works. Values like `anInvalidUuid` are rejected. I also tested the `@Unique` constraint in other use cases and it worked perfectly.

*What is the difference between `addItem()` and `toId()`?*

## Versions

I am using Java `1.8` and Spring Boot `2.0.0.RELEASE`. `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final` is on my classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation of method arguments is based on AOP: a validating proxy intercepts the method call and validates the argument before delegating (if everything is valid), to the actual method.

You're calling the `getCartItemId()` method from another method of the same class. So the method call doesn't go through the proxy. Only inter-bean calls can be intercepted.

So, in short, `getCartItemId` should be in a separate bean, injected into your controller.

Comment: Thank you, I moved `toId()` to a different class annotated with `@Component` (making it a bean) and `@Validated`. It works perfectly. I will try to find a cleaner solution, but your answer helped a lot.